# How to deal with overshoot in SVG fonts?

Tags: html, css, svg, webfonts

I have a very fancy font I want to use in SVG so I can combine it with other things in an SVG for a final product. It clips off the overhangs and other fancy bits beyond the base font size. How do I get those to show again? For some reason, the snippet is not reading my font URL but my own file reads and displays it fine, so do whatever you need to do to get it to work enough for testing purposes.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.cafenocturne.com/fonts/FontPorcelain.css" ?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 500 300">
    <defs>
      <filter id="dropshadow" width="250px" height="250px">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
      </filter>
    </defs>

    <text x="80" y="80" style="font-family: PorcelainRegular; 
   font-size: 80px;
   stroke: #000000;
   fill: #ffffff;
   filter: url(#dropshadow);">
      Cafe
    </text>
    <text x="80" y="150" style="font-family: PorcelainRegular; 
   font-size  : 80px;
   stroke     : #000000;
   fill       : #ffffff;
   filter: url(#dropshadow);">
      Nocturne
    </text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just the lack of a `viewBox` attribute? Try adding this inside your `<svg>` tag: `viewBox="0 0 500 300"`

Comment: I tried adding it and got no difference. What else do you suggest?

Comment: I don't see the error. Was this fixed after adding the viewBox attribute?

Comment: No. When I added in your exact viewbox code to my local copy, it still cut off the overshoots. Nothing changed.